# WebAPI Actions with multiple complex types, one of which is injected with a filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebAPI method as follows:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(ITradeCustomerPrincipal user, OrderModel value)
```

I get the error

> Can't bind multiple parameters ('user' and 'value') to the request's content.

When I try and call it. I understand why.

I have an attribute applied globally that injects the `ITradeCustomerPrincipal` into any action as below:

```
public class TradeConsumerFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var matchedArguments = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionBinding.ParameterBindings
                                            .SingleOrDefault(pb => typeof(ITradeCustomerPrincipal).IsAssignableFrom(pb.Descriptor.ParameterType));

        if (matchedArguments != null)
        {
            var TradeCustomerPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User as ITradeCustomerPrincipal;

            if (TradeCustomerPrincipal != null)
            {
                actionContext.ActionArguments[matchedArguments.Descriptor.ParameterName] = TradeCustomerPrincipal;
            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
}
```

In this way, actions don't need to bind the `ITradeCustomerPrincipal` themselves, it's done automatically by the attribute.

How can I tell the action not to bind the `user` parameter from the body (or anywhere I guess), as it's set by the action filter beforehand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get this working by creating a model binder that does nothing and applying it to the `user` parameter, which works fine since it's not a binder that assigns/creates the object anyway.

The model binder:

```
public class NoOpModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The new action method signature:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([ModelBinder(typeof(NoOpModelBinder))] ITradeCustomerPrincipal user, OrderModel value)
```

---

I've managed to figure out how to apply a model binder globally to an interface (you can't apply the attribute to an interface, only classes):

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.BindParameter(typeof(ITradeCustomerPrincipal), new NoOpModelBinder());
```

This means any action signature with this paramter works without the `ModelBinder` attribute.